# How do I delete the regular(jpg, png ) images after converting them to webp usging gulp?

Tags: gulp, webp, image-optimization

I'm new to gulp. Trying to optimize the images and convert them into `webp` format. I was able to achieve that using `gulp-webp`. But it seems there are now two version of the images inside my `dist/img` folder one is the original and a webp version. So how do I get only the webp not the original one inside my `dist/img`  folder?

Here how my project directories look like:

```
project
    |-dist
        |-css
        |-img
        |-js
    |-src
        |-css
        |-img
        |-js
    
    gulp.js
    ...
```

Here is `webp` conversion function:

```
function webpImage() {
    return src('dist/img/**/*.{jpg,png}')
        .pipe(imagewebp())
        .pipe(dest('dist/img'))
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would first say you should not delete source file, it is ok to keep them. What you want to do is having to different destinations. One of which should be deployed (the compiled, minified and webp for example) and the other should be version and used in your cdci pipelines perhaps.

But then, if you really want to remove the source file, you can use [gulp-clean](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-clean) while being in a gulp script.

Your gulp clean script could look like that :

```
const { src, task } = require('gulp');
const clean = require("gulp-clean");
const logger = require('node-color-log');

function cleanImagesTask() {
    const root = "path/to/images/you/want/to/delete";
    logger.color('yellow').log(`Clean images`);

    return src(root,{allowEmpty: true},{read: false}).pipe(clean({force:true}));
};

const cleanImagesFolder = task('clean:images', cleanImagesTask);
exports.cleanImagesFolder = cleanImagesFolder;
```

And if you want to deploy in a different dest, could use something similar to :

```
const { src, dest, task } = require( 'gulp' );
const logger = require('node-color-log');

function copyImagesToDest(callback) {
    const imagesSource = "path/to/your/images/**/*";
    const imagesDestination = "path/to/destination/";

    logger.color('green').log(`Copy images from ${artifactData} to: ${destination}`);

    return src(imagesSource)
            .pipe(dest(destination))
            .on('end', function () { 
                logger.color('green').log(`Copy to: ${destination}`);
                callback(); 
            });
};

const copyImages = task('copy:images', copyImagesToDest);
exports.copyImages = copyImages ;
```